# Where can i start being a web designer?

Tags: web-deployment

I'm a former IT-student and would like to start as a web-designer. because I'm still a student and want to focus on my study I don't want to work full time but part time.

does anyone know what's the best way is to do this. shoeld I start for my own or shoeld is apply for a job?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's requesting career advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question may not be what stackoverflow is supposed to be used for but I'll just give you some quick hints. Just like you I'm a young (19-year-old) student, currently studying Software Engineering (IT) at the Amsterdam University of Applied Sciences. I'm currently doing an internship (3rd year) and am working at a webdevelopment company. Look for Online Marketing companies near your home, send e-mails to them, just look around. Here in the Netherlands there are plenty of opportunities for you to start and grow. All you need is some base knowledge and something to show off (Even a small portfolio will help!). Put some time and effort into finding a part-time job.